# Possible to get vertices and indices of o3d.Shape?

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, o3d

I am using o3d webgl library with chrome nightly and minefield. I am looking for someone who knows how I can obtain the vertices and indices from an o3d.Shape object. The reason why I would like to do this is so that I can utilize the primitive objects within the picking demo from the latest distribution.

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to vertices or indices, the object can be added to the scene directly and is picked up by the picking manager